# "Incorrect decryption" in decryption RSA python code

Tags: python, base64, rsa

i have this code that suppose to decode base64 encoded RSA text (by its key) but it doesn't work.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import binascii
import base64

f = open('mykey.pem','r')
keyPair = RSA.import_key(f.read())

encoded = b'base64_encoded_text'
encrypted = base64.decodebytes(encoded)

decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(keyPair)
decrypted = decryptor.decrypt(encrypted)
print('Decrypted:', decrypted)
```

The error is: "Incorrect decryption". 
Does somebody know what could be the problem?

Comment: `b'base64_encoded_text'` isn't base64 encoded text.

Comment: The problem is either the key is wrong or the cipher has been corrupted.